How do I express wildcard value with CONCAT in T-SQL?
I have these file names:
WH_BEE_FULL_20241014_170853_1.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241014_170853_2.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241014_170853_3.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241014_170853_4.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241014_170853_5.bak
WH_BEE_FULL_20241014_170853_6.bak

I am trying to use a wildcard (similar to *) with concat in a part of T-SQL script where it points to to where files are located.
Basically, I am having an issue to express '170853'.
I am trying to just use a wildcard to ignore any different pattern that would occur.
Bottom is the whole T-SQL that I run to restore DB, but only the area that needs attention is where it starts with 'CONCAT'.
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @maxInputFiles BIGINT = 6;

WITH L1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n(n)
),
L2 AS (
    SELECT 1 n
    FROM L1 AS a, L1 AS b
)
SELECT @sql = N'
RESTORE DATABASE [WH_BEE]
FROM ' +
  STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT('
DISK = N''F:\Test\WH_BEE_FULL',
      '_',
      convert(varchar(8),cast(GETDATE()-3 as date),112),
      '_',
      '%',
      '_',
      g.value,        
      '.bak'''
    ),
    ', '
  ) + N'
WITH REPLACE, FILE = 1, 
MOVE N''WH_Data1'' TO N''F:\data2022\WH_BEE.MDF'',  
MOVE N''WH_Data2'' TO N''F:\data2022\WH_BEE_1.NDF'',  
MOVE N''WH_Log'' TO N''G:\log2022\WH_BEE.LDF'', STATS = 5;
'
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@maxInputFiles)
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS value
    FROM L2
) AS g;


EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @sql;


You can't use wildcard in filename for RESTORE. Use full filename

Seems like you're doing this from the wrong side. Rather than using SQL Server to use wildcards to find the files (which it can't do), use a CLI (PowerShell for example) to locate the files, and then create and execute the statement on SQL Server using the details of the files the script found.
